# Running .NET unit tests within a Linux container on a Windows PC

Tags: unit-testing, docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application, which spins up from `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0` on a Debian Docker environment. I have a test project with a few test methods, and one of them is kind of special:

It has to run a shell command (in `/bin/bash`) on the container.

Since I run Windows, it gives me an

> The system cannot find the file specified`

because it's trying to run `/bin/bash {COMMAND HERE}`, which makes sense.

Right now it simply runs the .NET Core project, so everything works up until the point where it tries to run that command.

How exactly do I debug with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` inside my Docker container?

Comment: you can build a container which does the tests and then run xunit / dotnet test in that container.
I use multistage builds to do this and it works well, albewit without VS integration

Comment: Addendum: if the bash script is simple, you could replace it with a Powershell 6# script, which can run on linux and windows

Comment: "It has to run a shell command (in /bin/bash) on the container." What exactly is that? You might be able to rewrite it in PowerShell (like @ChristianSauer suggests) or even in C#.

Comment: @ChristianSauer and @LexLi - The problem is that I install google-chrome-stable using a long `apt-get install` with packages and a bunch of other commands, so I can simply do `google-chrome-stable {COMMANDS}`. I can't apt-get on my Windows machine, unless I have a statement that says "if Windows, run Ubuntu Shell" (or whatever it's called), but then it would require everyone running my tests to have the Ubuntu shell on their Windows machine.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Than I would use the "test in the container idea", e.g have a multistage build where the nuget packages are pulled first, then a build the project, run the tests and if successful publish the result.
You can use the netcore 2 dockerfile as a baseline and add a testing step

Comment: @ChristianSauer Yeah I've thought about that as well  and it seems like it might be the best idea. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

The description of how to run and debug the "test in the container idea" for the .NET Core 3.1 can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63457468/538435).

If you take the .NET Core SDK Linux container as a base, it already includes bash, so it should work fine.

Copying below info on debugging from the linked answer. To debug you have to define environment variable on Linux VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG=1. Assuming your source code is on D drive and you build output d:\src\acmeproject\acmetests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\acmetests.dll the command line to debug specific test on Linux container could go like

```
docker run --rm --name AcmeUnitTest -e VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG=1 -v d:\:/mnt/d/ -w /mnt/d/src/acmeproject/acmetests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 dotnet test acmetests.dll --filter Name~AcmeTestMethod
```